# javascript click function not working in asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm having following asp.net mvc 5 web application view page , Prevously its worked very well.

```
@model project_name.Models.SearchBrochureVM

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Brochure_Create";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h4>Product Brochure Generation</h4>


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{

    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    <div class="form-group"></div>


    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Type, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Type, Model.TypeList, "Select the type", new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Type, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Category, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Category, Model.CategoryList, "Select the category", new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Category, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div>
        &nbsp;
    </div>

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Country, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Country, Model.CountryList, "Select the country", new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Country, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Product, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Product, Model.ProductList, "Select the subsidary", new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Product, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        &nbsp;
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <button id="search" type="button" class="btn btn-success submit">Select Information</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

}
<form id="brochureform">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Property_ID</th>
                <th>IsChecked</th>
                <th>Property Tile</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="table"></tbody>
    </table>
</form>

    <table id="template" class="table" style="display: none;">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span></span>
                <input type="hidden" name="[#].Property_ID" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="[#].IsChecked" value="true"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="[#].IsChecked" value="false"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span></span>
            </td>
        </tr>


    </table>
    <div style="width:50%; float:left;text-align:left"><button id="resetborchure" type="button" class="btn btn-warning submit">Reset Brochure</button> </div>
    <div style="width:50%; float:left;text-align:right"><button id="createborchure" type="button" class="btn btn-danger submit">Create Brochure</button> </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    </script>

    @section Scripts {
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")


        <script type="text/javascript">

             var type = $('#Type');
            var category = $('#Category');
            var country = $('#Country');
            var product = $('#Product');

            $('#search').click(function () {

                var url = '@Url.Action("FetchProductProperties")';

                $.getJSON(url, { type: type.val(), category: category.val(), country: country.val(), product: product.val() }, function (data) {
                    $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                        var clone = $('#template').clone();
                        clone.html($(clone).html().replace(/\[#\]/g, '[' + index + ']'));
                        var cells = clone.find('td');
                        cells.eq(0).children('span').text(item.ID);
                        cells.eq(0).children('input').val(item.ID);
                        cells.eq(1).children('input').first().prop('checked', item.CheckOrNot)
                        cells.eq(2).children('span').text(item.Name);
                        $('#table').append(clone.find('tr'));
                    });
                });
            });

            $('#createborchure').click(function () {

                var data = $('#brochureform').serialize();
                var url = '@Url.Action("Create_Brochure", "Brochure")';

                //$.get(url, data, function (result) {
                //    window.location = url;
                //});

               $.ajax({
                    url: url,                   
                    type: 'GET',                    
                    data: data
                })
                    .success(function (response) {
                     });

            });



            $('#resetborchure').click(function () {              
                table.empty();
            });

</script>


    }
```

Above view have two buttons called **Reset Brochure** and **Create Brochure**

Once I click **Reset Brochure** button its clear the table in that view and once I select **Create Brochure** its redirect to another view.

previously these two functions worked very well , but I cannot understand this isn't give any response once I click these buttons.

Comment: Check for the error in Browser's Console.

Comment: what should I check  ? can you mention few steps

Comment: Try unwrapping `js` code from `@section Scripts { }` and write `javascripts` directly

Comment: If you are using chrome, press F-12 and then click Console Tab then tell me what do you see? That is browser's console for chrome.

Comment: @GuruprasadRao As you said I brought out script codes , but looks like reults is same

Comment: @WaqarAhmed this is the view in firebug http://s15.postimg.org/w3252toa3/cons.png

Comment: @Kez.. click on **All** tab in your `console`.. You should get to see the error..

Comment: Well for not redirecting to another view, your redirecting code is commented in createborchure function.

Comment: @GuruprasadRao is the error http://s29.postimg.org/fi2dmhbmf/cwe.jpg

Comment: You have some error in your `CSS` may be `jquery-theme.css` **line 16**.. Just click of **Errors** tab and see what else `errors` you have?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao then I got like this http://s14.postimg.org/5s9ds3dm9/vcxz.jpg

Comment: Where you have referred that `table` ? It should have been `$('#table').empty()` right?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao once I use this `$('#table').empty()` its doing empty the table , but ajax function still not working

Comment: Hard bind the `url` as `url="/Brochure/Create_Brochure"`

Comment: `table.empty();` would not do anything because you have not declared `table` anywhere (it would be undefined) - you would need `var table = $('#table');` or use `$('#table').empty();` And your ajax in `createborchure` does not do anything in the success callback (not sure what your wanting to do)

Comment: @StephenMuecke all the method you said for "Reset Brochure" button is working ,but once I click "Create Brochure" button I want to direct to another action, thats not happening

Comment: The success call back in the ajax method of "Create Brochure" does not do anything. If you want to redirect then add `location.href='someUrl';` And if the "Reset Brochure" is working then you do have `var table = $('#table');` somewhere - you just have not included it in the code you posted :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke what I want to do is something like this http://s18.postimg.org/6cnybk2uh/saveee.jpg please can you show me the path

Comment: Then just add `location.href='@Url.Action("CreateBrochure")';` inside the `success` callback (or whatever the GET method is named)

Comment: But since you want to redirect, there is no real point using ajax for this anyway. Just use a normal form submit.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I cannot understand exactly what you said, do I need more changes in these codes https://dotnetfiddle.net/VklMaw

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92714/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-kez).

Comment: @StephenMuecke as you said I changed script and did like this https://dotnetfiddle.net/MYHnTd

Comment: @StephenMuecke as you said When I click Create Brochure button its generating a link like this `http://localhost:49669/Brochure/Product_Properties_Search?[0].Property_ID=1&[0].IsChecked=true&[0].IsChecked=false&[1].Property_ID=2&[1].IsChecked=true&[1].IsChecked=false&[2].Property_ID=3&[2].IsChecked=false&[3].Property_ID=4&[3].IsChecked=false&[4].Property_ID=5&[4].IsChecked=false&[5].Property_ID=6&[5].IsChecked=false&[6].Property_ID=7&[6].IsChecked=false&[7].Property_ID=8&[7].IsChecked=false&[8].Property_ID=9&[8].IsChecked=false&[9].Property_ID=10&[9].IsChecked=false` quite ugly one

Comment: @StephenMuecke but once I click `Create Brochure` button its not directing to `Create_Brochure` View page, only change its URL. I'd like to try that you suggested `use a POST to an intermediate action` can you refer example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your wanting to redirect to another method (passing the values of the form controls in the table) there is no reason to use ajax, and instead you should just do a normal submit.

Replace the `<form id="brochureform">` element with

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create_Brochure", "Brochure", FormMethod.Get))
{
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            ....
        </thead>
        <tbody id="table"></tbody>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="CreateBrochure" />
}
```

and remove the `<button id="createborchure" ...>Create Brochure</button>` element and its associated script. This will now make a GET call to your `public ActionResult Create_Brochure(IEnumerable<ProductsPropertiesVM> model)` method

However this will also create a really ugly url and there is a risk that you will exceed the query string limit and throw an exception. In general GET methods should never have parameters which are collections.

From the [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VklMaw) you provided in chat, its unclear how your using the data you pass to the method (your create a variable `string ids` but then never actually use it. Assuming you do actually need it for the view you return in that method, I would suggest adding another POST method to avoid the issues above.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Initialize_Brochure(IEnumerable<ProductsPropertiesVM> model)
{
    IEnumerable<int> selectedIDs = model.Where(x => x.IsChecked).Select(x => x.Property_ID);
    string ids = string.Join(",", selectedIDs);
    return RedirectToAction("Create_Brochure", new { id = ids });
}
```

and change the `Create_Brochure()` method to

```
public ActionResult Create_Brochure(string id)
{
    ....
}
```

and finally modify the `BeginForm()` to

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Initialize_Brochure", "Brochure", FormMethod.Post))
```

This means you url will simply be something like
 `/Brochure/Initialize_Brochure/2,4,5` depending on the checkboxes you select